# Why aren't placeholders for std::bind implemented using non-type template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, stdbind

I know the question is rather theoretical but I think if placeholders would be defined as the template like e.g.:

```
namespace std { 
   namespace placeholders {
      template <size_t> struct placeholder { constexpr placeholder() {}; }; 
      template <size_t N> constexpr placeholder<N> _{};
   }
}
```

with usage:

```
std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_<1>, std::placeholders::_<2>);
```

Or for c++11:

```
namespace std { 
   namespace placeholders {
      template <size_t> struct _ { }; 
   }
}
```

with usage:

```
std::bind(foo, std::placeholders::_<1>{}, std::placeholders::_<2>{});
```

the code wouldn't loose anything of its clearness and we would be able to do some fancy metaprogramming using it. So... why aren't placeholders for `std::bind` implemented using non-type template parameters?

Comment: That syntax doesn't look legal.  `_<1>` is still a type, and you cannot pass a type as a value: you'd need `_<1>{}` at the least, no?  Or `template<size_t> struct placeholder {constexpr placeholder() {};}; template<size_t N> constexpr placeholder<N> _{};`?  And when you get to the 2nd, well then you'd need variable templates, which did not exist in C++11.  So, what do you want to know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variable templates did not exist in C++11, which is where `std::bind` was added to the language.

The `_1` names where short, and taken from `boost` where `std::bind` was developed.

You can write your own similar placeholders easily.

```
namespace my_placeholders {
  template <int> struct placeholder { constexpr placeholder() {}; }; 
  template <int N> constexpr placeholder<N> _{};
}
namespace std {
  template<int N>
  struct is_placeholder< ::my_placeholders::placeholder<N> >:
    std::integral_constant<int, N>
  {};
}
```

and now `my_placeholders::_<1>` is a valid `std::bind` placeholder equivalent to `_1` in every important way.

Given the ability to do this, and frankly how annoying it is to work with `std::bind` in comparison to lambda, I could see nobody bothering to actually add such a feature to the standard post C++14.